# Turn unknown object into object of a specific type if shape of input object satisfies the type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a function in TypeScript that takes as input an object with an unknown number of unknown properties, and returns an object of type `Person`.

- if there are additional properties in the input object, that are not in the `Person` type, then those should be dropped from the output.
- if required properties in `Person` are missing from the input, an error should be thrown.

Is there an elegant way to do this, without having to do a bunch of if statements for each property?

```
interface Person {
   name: string;
   address: Address;
}

interface Address {
  street1: string;
  street2?: string;
  city: string;
  state: string;
  zip: string;
  phone?: string;
}
```

Comment: Can you include some test cases? I'm not totally sure right now what you want exactly

Comment: Types don't exist at runtime. But it sounds like you want [zod](https://zod.dev/)

Comment: Zod is what I needed. Thanks! Couldn't figure out how to check types at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Types don't exist at runtime. I ended up using [Zod](https://zod.dev/).

With Zod's `safeParse()`, one can define a schema first and then attempt to parse an object into that schema.

```
//first, define the schema

const Address = z.object({
  street1: z.string(),
  street2: z.string().optional(),
  city: z.string(),
  state: z.string(),
  zip: z.string(),
  phone: z.string().optional(),
});

const Person = z.object({
  name: z.string(),
  address: Address.optional(), //remove .optional() to see the error message Zod will throw
});


//next, parse an object into that schema

const randomInputObject = {
  name: 'John Doe',
  age: 123,
};

const result = Person.safeParse(randomInputObject);
console.log(result); //success...
```

[Playground here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-22oqbl?file=index.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way you can 'tell' typescript, that an argument is of type Person.
Thus typescript has nothing to do with runtime, you need to write safe runtime checks inside function to ensure, that an object is like Person interface.

```
function isPerson(obj: unknown): obj is Person{
  // TODO: write runtime checks here and return boolean(whether the object is a person or not)
  return true;
}

const maybePerson: unknown = { };

if(isPerson(maybePerson)){
  // maybePerson extends Person
}
```